# Promises Sequenciais - Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Estou tentando criar uma cadeia de Promises sequenciais no Node.js e ele não esta executando uma de cada vez e sim todas!

**Deveria executar da seguinte forma:**

Promise1 -> (then) -> Promise2 -> (then) -> Promise3 ...

Mas no meu caso, ele está executando todas ao mesmo tempo.
O código é o seguinte:

```
router.post('/entrega', (req, res) => {

    let pedido = new PedidoDao(req.body);

    Promise.resolve(pedido.isEntregue())
    .then(pedido.setEntrega())
    .then(responseSuccess())
    .catch( err => responseError(err))

    function responseSuccess(){
        res.json({status:true, message: 'Entrega realizada com sucesso.'});
    }

    function responseError(message){
        res.json({status:false, message: message});
    }

});
```

Todas as funções de PedidoDao retornam uma promise(resolve, reject).

Eu fiz a função setEntrega() retornar um reject proposital, mas mesmo assim a função responseSucces é executada de cara. Depois de 1 segundo estoura o reject da função setEntrega e cai no catch, porém já houve uma resposta de sucesso na API.

Pode ser que eu esteja viajando, mas eu não queria usar async/await para fazer esse tipo de sequenciamento. Será possível fazer com Promise ou não?

Forte abraço.

EDIT: Possível solução
Fiz essa edição no código e agora ele está seguindo a sequência... Seria este o modo correto de escrever mesmo?

```
router.post('/entrega', (req, res) => {

    let pedido = new PedidoDao(req.body);

    Promise.resolve(pedido.isEntregue())
    .then(() => pedido.setEntrega())
    .then(() => responseSuccess())
    .catch( err => responseError(err))

    function responseSuccess(){
        res.json({status:true, message: 'Entrega realizada com sucesso.'});
    }

    function responseError(message){
        res.json({status:false, message: message});
    }

});
```

Comment: @Sorack fiz a alteração, adicionei o código :D

Comment: Consegue fazer um exemplo [mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para podermos te ajudar?

Comment: O `async/await` também lida com `Promise`, só de um jeito mais legível

Comment: @Sorack para este caso, seria mais recomendado utilizar o sync/await?

Comment: Eu acredito que o código fique mais limpo e legível, mas aí vai de como você está estruturando sua aplicação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você só está executando a função sem retornar a promessa da função subsequente. Então você pode mudar seu código para:

```
// ...
Promise.resolve(pedido.isEntregue())
  .then(function() { return pedido.setEntrega(); })
  .then(function() { return responseSuccess(); })
  .catch(err => responseError(err));
// ...
```

Ou:

```
// ...
Promise.resolve(pedido.isEntregue())
  .then(pedido.setEntrega)
  .then(responseSuccess)
  .catch(err => responseError(err));
// ...
```

Dessa forma você informa para o encadeamento qual a promessa que ele deve aguardar.