# A minha API em node js mistura dados de diferentes requests

Tags: node.js, concorrência

Eu desenvolvi uma app privada em zapier.com. A framework é em node js. E é composta por triggers e actions.

Numa das minhas actions, quando é desplotado o vários triggers em simultâneo fico com dados misturados.

Eu gostaria de perceber como prevenir esta situação.

```
/***

Zapier Action
@autor Pedro Correia, from Portugal
@company NovosCanais
@date 27-11-2019

***/
// O zapier sempre que encontra uma ',' coloca a string em formato de array e faz split
function validacoes(){
  if (bundle.inputData.nome) {
    if (Array.isArray(bundle.inputData.nome) && bundle.inputData.nome.length){
      bundle.inputData.nome.join(', ');
    }
  }
  if (bundle.inputData.email) {
    if (Array.isArray(bundle.inputData.email) && bundle.inputData.email.length){
      bundle.inputData.email.join(', ');
      z.console.log(bundle.inputData.email);
    }
  }
  if (bundle.inputData.morada) {
    if (Array.isArray(bundle.inputData.morada) && bundle.inputData.morada.length){
      bundle.inputData.morada.join(' and ');
      z.console.log(bundle.inputData.morada);
    }
  }
  if (bundle.inputData.codpost) {
    if (Array.isArray(bundle.inputData.codpost) && bundle.inputData.codpost.length){
      bundle.inputData.codpost.join(', ');
    }
  }
  if (bundle.inputData.local) {
    if (Array.isArray(bundle.inputData.local) && bundle.inputData.local.length){
      bundle.inputData.local.join(', ');
    }
  }

}
validacoes();
// 1º fazemos um search sobre os clientes
// uma vez que garantidamente temos um número de contribuinte que é identificador do cliente
let options = {
  url: 'https://api.drivefx.net/v3/searchEntities',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': process.env.API_KEY
  },
  body: {

        "queryObject": {
        "distinct": false,
        "entityName": "cl",
        "filterCod": "",
        "filterItems": [{
        "filterItem": "ncont",
        "comparison": 0,
        "valueItem": bundle.inputData.ncont,
        "groupItem": 0
        }],
        "SelectItems": ["*"]
        }

  }
}

// globals

let log;

// Procura cliente, caso não exista cria um com os dados que recebeu
return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    // *** log
    let clientes = z.JSON.parse(response.content);
    let no;
    if (Array.isArray(clientes.entities) && clientes.entities.length){
        // Entrei aqui: então não preciso criar cliente
        //*** Atualizamos o cliente antigo?????????????
        no = clientes.entities[0].no;

        // update cl
        clientes.entities[0].email = (bundle.inputData.email) ? bundle.inputData.email : "";
        clientes.entities[0].morada = (bundle.inputData.morada) ? bundle.inputData.morada : "";
        clientes.entities[0].codpost = (bundle.inputData.codpost) ? bundle.inputData.codpost : "";
        clientes.entities[0].local = (bundle.inputData.local) ? bundle.inputData.local : "";

        return criarClienteAndFatura(true, clientes.entities[0], no);

    } else {
        // Entrei aqui: então vou criar o cliente no driveFX
        // 1º buscamos uma instancia default do cliente

        return criarClienteAndFatura(false, null);      
    }

  });


function criarClienteAndFatura(updateCl, cliente_searched, no) {


    if (updateCl && cliente_searched) {



        let options = {
          url: 'https://api.drivefx.net/v3/saveInstance',
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': process.env.API_KEY
          },
          body: {
            "entity" : "Cl",
            "ndoc" : 1,
            "itemVO" : cliente_searched
          }
        }

        return z.request(options)
          .then((response) => {
            response.throwForStatus();
            // *** log
            log = response.content;
            z.console.log(response.content);
            let results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

            // callback
            return criarFatura(no);
          });
    }
    else {
        let options = {
            url: 'https://api.drivefx.net/v3/getNew',
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Authorization': process.env.API_KEY
              },
              body: {
                "entity" : "Cl",
                "ndoc" : 1
              }
            }

            return z.request(options)
              .then((response) => {
                response.throwForStatus();
                // *** log
                    z.console.log(response.content);
                // parse instance
                let novoCliente = z.JSON.parse(response.content);
                no = novoCliente.no;
                // set instance
                novoCliente.nome = (bundle.inputData.nome) ? bundle.inputData.nome : "";
                novoCliente.email = (bundle.inputData.email) ? bundle.inputData.email : "";
                novoCliente.morada = (bundle.inputData.morada) ? bundle.inputData.morada : "";
                novoCliente.codpost = (bundle.inputData.codpost) ? bundle.inputData.codpost : "";
                novoCliente.local = (bundle.inputData.local) ? bundle.inputData.local : "";
                novoCliente.ncont = (bundle.inputData.ncont) ? bundle.inputData.ncont : "";
                z.console.log(novoCliente.nome + " nome");
                // save instance
                let options = {
                  url: 'https://api.drivefx.net/v3/saveInstance',
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Authorization': process.env.API_KEY
                  },
                  body: {
                    "entity" : "Cl",
                    "ndoc" : 1,
                    "itemVO" : novoCliente
                  }
                }

                return z.request(options)
                  .then((response) => {
                    response.throwForStatus();
                    // *** log
                    z.console.log(response.content);
                    let results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

                    // callback
                    return criarFatura(no);
                  });

              });
    }
}


            z.console.log('after create FT2');

function criarFatura(no){
    /***
        Cliente existe ou foi criado
        Agora vamos faturar
    ***/

    options = {
        url: 'https://api.drivefx.net/v3/getNew',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': process.env.API_KEY
        },
        body: {
            "entity" : "Ft",
            "ndoc" : 1 // número da série de documentação ***poderemos ter de alterar
        }
    }



    return z.request(options)
        .then((response) => {
        response.throwForStatus();
        z.console.log("Entrei fatura");
        let fatura = z.JSON.parse(response.content);
        let ref;
        let codigo_da_obra;

        if (no) {

            z.console.log(no);
            fatura.no=no;
            fatura.u6530_inscricao.inscricaoid = (bundle.inputData.ninscricao) ? bundle.inputData.ninscricao : "";
            fatura.u6530_inscricao.id_egoi = (bundle.inputData.id) ? bundle.inputData.id : "";
            fatura.u6530_inscricao.email_e = (bundle.inputData.email_e) ? bundle.inputData.email_e : "";
            fatura.u6530_inscricao.vem_do_egoi = true;
            fatura.u6530_inscricao.atualizou_egoi = false;
            fatura.u6530_inscricao.nome_formando = (bundle.inputData.nome_formando) ? bundle.inputData.nome_formando : "";
            // trabalhar o codInterno
          z.console.log(fatura.u6530_inscricao.inscricaoid);
            let split = bundle.inputData.codInterno.split('_');
            codigo_da_obra = split[0];
            ref = split[1];
            z.console.log(ref);
            fatura.fis.push({ref: ref, qtt: (bundle.inputData.qtt) ? bundle.inputData.qtt : "", epv: (bundle.inputData.epv) ? bundle.inputData.epv : 0, u6530_faturas_obras_adp: {codigo_da_obra: codigo_da_obra}});

        }

        // save instance
        let options = {
            url: 'https://api.drivefx.net/v3/saveInstance',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': process.env.API_KEY
            },
            body: {
                "entity" : "Ft",
                "ndoc" : 1,
                "itemVO" : fatura
            }
        }

        return z.request(options)
            .then((response) => {
            response.throwForStatus();
            z.console.log(response.content);
            const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);

            return results; 
        });
    });  

}
```

Se eu declarar as variáveis como var ele não vai misturar os dados?

Comment: Me parece o caso de verificar as promessas do seu código. Talvez [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368100/promises-sequenciais-node/368108#368108) possa te ajudar a entender o problema.

Comment: Gostava de perceber se para diferentes requests, as váriaveis do objeto window fazem overwrite.

Comment: vc tem que escutar isso, com observe: [obj.observe()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) ou o mais recente proxy: [var p = new Proxy(target, handler);](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: E desta forma vc organiza seus eventos de maneira que não se atropelem.

Answer (score 0):

No post que fizeste está a usar uma [API do drivefx](https://api.drivefx.net/v3/).

Já usastes por acaso [este](https://developer.drivefx.net/app/webapp/) em que os endpoints são https://developer.drivefx.net/app/webapp/Metodos/?

Se sim conseguiste fazer login com o endpoint https://sis10.drivefx.net/XXXXXX/rest/UserLoginWS/userLogin?

Em relação ao teu post recomendava que em vez dos callbacks passares a usar `Promises` e melhor ainda usar `async`/`await` que torna mais legível o código e seria mais fácil perceberes se nalguma altura não estás a forçar esperar pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver é fazer um callback de eventos em fila, cada vez que um evento for resolvido, você chama o próximo, daí no final apresenta os dados, exemplo:

```
init = (callback, resolveFinal) => {
 const data = [];
   callback()

 if(typeof resolveFinal !== 'undefined' && resolveFinal) {
      if(data.length == 3) {
         return data;    
      }


 }

}
const data = {
 result
init((results) => {
    Servico1.metodo().then((data) => {
      results.push(data)
      init((results) => {
          Servico2.metodo().then((data) => {
                results.push(data)
                  init((results, resolve) => {
                       Servico3.metodo().then((data) => {
                           results.push(data)
                           resolve(results);
                       })
                  })
          })
       })
    })
});
```